# WindowChrome button not hit-test visible when disabled

Tags: wpf, window-chrome

In `WPF` you can customize the caption bar using [WindowChrome](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Adding buttons in the non-client area is fairly simple as long as you remember to set `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"`.

Now, there is a bug or unexpected/weird behavior when a **disabled** button is **double-clicked**. Nothing should happen, but instead the app is maximized.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a new `WPF` project. Preferably targeting `.NET 6`.
2. Paste the code below in `MainWindow.xaml`.
3. Run the app and double-click the button.

**Expected:** Nothing happens

**Actual:** The app is maximized

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfChromeTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowStyle="None" Height="450" Width="800">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="20" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Window.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="200" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Content="I'm disabled! DOUBLE-CLICK ME!"
                        WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                        IsEnabled="False" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Template>
</Window>
```

What am I missing here? Is it a bug? And if so, is there a workaround?

### Update

The accepted answer got it right. The reason why it works can be seen in [WindowChromeWorker.cs(670)](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/7511ae4c2e11d8eabb50a5ee9ee1b7c377b915fc/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Shell/WindowChromeWorker.cs#L670) where the call to [UIElement.InputHitTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) will indeed skip any disabled element. However, on [line 673](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/7511ae4c2e11d8eabb50a5ee9ee1b7c377b915fc/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Shell/WindowChromeWorker.cs#L673) we find the magic that allows for the suggested solution:

When the parent element has `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome` set to `true`, the callback will correctly return `HTCLIENT`, effectively swallowing our double click.

In the provided sample, we could simply replace `<Grid>` with the following, to get the desired behavior:

```xml
<Grid WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double clicking on the title bar causes the window to change its state,

1. when the button is enabled, the double click will be handled by the button and not passed to the title bar.
2. when the button is disabled, the double click will be passed to the title bar, this will happen if you replace the button with any disabled UIElement.

So the current behavior is normal.

> Is there a workaround?

Yes, If you want to disable WindowState change regardless of the button's `IsEnabled` value, wrap `<Button/>` with another UI element that will prevent the double click from being passed to the window's title bar if the button is disabled.

```
<ContentControl
    Grid.Row="0"
    Width="200"
    Height="28"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
    <Button
        x:Name="MyButton"
        Content="I'm disabled! DOUBLE-CLICK ME!"
        IsEnabled="False" />
</ContentControl>
```